# Contests with Calculus Questions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, contest-math

I am self studying [Thomas's Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134439023), a popular Calculus textbook in the US and a few other countries. It covers the standard theorems and properties, the easier proofs, standard numericals and some simple applications. In non-calculus maths, I have seen that contest math questions tend to be more difficult, require more creativity, and better test understanding of concepts in a larger context.

A couple of contests that I know have Calculus questions include:

- [Mu Alpha Theta](https://mualphatheta.org/past_tests): Some nice questions which assume the same concepts that Thomas does, but more creative applications.
- [Putnam](https://www.maa.org/math-competitions/putnam-competition) Some very difficult questions (possibly too difficult to be done immediately after Thomas).

Are there any other sources from where I can get questions for Calculus?
Also, what books would be recommended after finishing Thomas?

Having solutions for the problems is very important, since I am self-studying. I will almost always go with a source that has solutions which can be checked when I can get stuck, or make the inevitable mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are contests like HMMT (Harvard MIT math tournament) or SUMO(Stanford University Math Tournament) contain problems from calculus which can be solved by high school students (these exams are specifically for high school students).

Other than that you can also look up on aops (art of problem solving) It is a website where in the community forum there are many problems from contest mathematics (which include calculus and loads of other things).

If you are looking for some advanced problems (not as hard as Putnam, IMO) you can look up the 'Stuart Sidney Calculus Competition' beware that this is for undergraduate students.

After Thomas's book you can read
[Spivak's Book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.in/Calculus-Michael-Spivak/dp/0914098918&ved=2ahUKEwjbouSFkYv1AhUo7XMBHc7UBI4QFnoECCkQAQ&sqi=2&usg=AOvVaw02Wdl19-kRviPRmHVySX7m).

If you happen to be interested in real analysis ( a field of mathematics formalizing calculus roughly speaking ) you might want to check out Rudin's famous book 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis'.

Answer (score 1):

I know some exercise books that are very popular in China. However, there seems to be no translated versions for these books. However, there are indeed some famous books that includes interesting topics as exercise problems. My recommandation is the exercises in Zorich's *Mathematical Analysis*, and Polya's *Problems and theorems in analysis*. These books contains problems that are challenging and interesting.